# EAS building fails with package.json error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Using Managed workflow

Your eas-cli version

- eas-cli/2.7.0
- win32-x64
- node-v16.10.0

What you have tried so far

- Clicked through every link on Google I could find (none mentioned this error specifically)
- Read the Expo Documentation as well as Troubleshooting Guide
- Ensured that the package.json is in the root directory

Error: *package.json does not exist in /Users/expo/workingdir/build*

I am building for iOS and having no issues up to the ‘Prepare Project’ phase. Each subsequent fails with the same error.

I have no idea where the ‘/Users/expo/workingdir/build’ directory actually is, as I don’t have an ‘expo’ user on my machine. Do I need to create these directories?
[image]

I don't post here so let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: Hi. did you find a solution for this?. am also facing the same issue

Comment: @FaithGaiciumia Is this issue solved? Please enlighten me too with this.